# Where to put user claims in Identity Server 4

Tags: sql, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I am using Identity Server 4 to manage my logins for all applications in my organization.
So I have IdentityServer 4 deployed and connected to sql server database.
Now I have 5 client applications that each has it's own roles/claims (ie app 1 has manager, accountant, while app 2 has developer, manager, electrician, app 3 has designer, administrator, reviewer...). 
My question is:
Do I put those user role/claims in Identityserver4 database or should each application have its own database holding its own user roles/claims?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by adding one extra table to IdentityServer Database,like RoleClientAuthorizations. You need to hold RoleId,ClientId and AuthorizationLevel in this table.

Then you can return all claims about that client in ProfileService at runtime.

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IClientService _clientService;
    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,IClientService clientService)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        _clientService = clientService;
    }
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        var clientId = context.Client.ClientId;

        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

        --You will get role client information from RoleClientAuthorization table here
        var userAuthorizationLevelClaim = _clientService.GetUserAuthorizationLevel(clientId, sub);
        if(userAuthorizationLevelClaim != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("authorizationLevelCode", userAuthorizationLevelClaim.AuthorizationLevelId.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("authorizationPrivilegeType", userAuthorizationLevelClaim.PrivilegeType));
        }

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
```

In startup;

```
services.AddIdentity()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Comment: Thanks, so Your solution is to put them in the IdentityServer db... I see the advantages of this. But,  to manage client aplication roles, the client application sould then have access right to modify IdentityServer 4 db. I will try this solution...

Comment: Actually, clients dont need to access IdentityServerDb, I managed it with a common application which is used by only sys admins, from this application you can manage all client and their roles by adding data to RoleClientAuthorization table. I know it is a bit more work but I think it is the best solution.

Comment: If it would be ok, I would be glad if you up my answer :)

Comment: Thanks again, you're right. I would like to know how you then "connect" that roles to your own data in client application? (ie. if I have Projects table in my client app, how do you specify what project user has access to (CRUD operations)?) Thanks again

Comment: At that point, you should solve it in your api endpoints.If you are using common api for all clients it will be hard to manage it. Otherwise, you can specify that ie. roleX can access AddProject method via (Roles="Admin") attribute above an endpoint

Comment: Thanks, it will do.

Answer (score 1):

It's sounding a little like you're mixing up authentication and authorization. Your identity shouldn't change from App to App - who you are and what you are made up of is a constant (ish) and your identity shouldn't change just because you're now on a different application.
Yes, your *roles* might change from app to app, and your permissions and authorization decisions, but not your identity.
https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Using IdentityServer for managing identity, and issuing proof-of-identity is great but you should look for a different solution for authorizing the user within your applications ... something that lets those applications decide whether, given the identity provided, the user is allowed to *do the thing*. This may be role based, or something more involved. This means you should manage the application roles a user has *with each application*, not with identity server.

Comment: I agree, each application manages it's permissions.The problem is mapping between authenticated user and it's roles/claims on the application. If I put roles/claims into IS4 then I can get them in the token when I authenticate the user. If I put them in applications, then I need to keep track of the users and it's roles in all my applications, end this can led to duplicates (both IS4 and application must contain users data), harder configuration (have to create more user management interfaces one for IS4 and one per each application, and configure the same users on both ends), and maybe more.

Comment: Or you create a centralised authorization system (see PolicyServer for an example of how the IdentityServer creators imagine an Authorization system to work). You could say that that 'both IS4 and application must contain user data', or you could look at it like 'IS4 contains identity information, applications contain data on what an identity can do *in this application*. Yes it is 'user data' but for completely different purposes: one is to prove authentication, the other is to prove authorisation.

Comment: You don't need to maintain full user data in your application (like repeating email address, first name, etc) just the data that joins up an identity (for example, on the sub-claim) with the application specific user data ... like roles, permissions, or whatever you want for that application.